# vim directory is a mess

Tags: linux, vim

kinda new to linux.

anyway, when i was virgin new to vim/linux i stupidly modified my vim folder directly in /usr/share/vim   (altered vimrc and some plugin, autoload type stuff), and kind of made a mess up it.

/usr/share/vim links to etc/vim.

im having difficulty understanding how i should set up a /vim in my home directory. which is what i shouldve been doing all along.

***note*** - i didnt alter anything too crazily in the /usr/vim and would be okay with restoring everything to the default and just copying my vimrc contents into the new .vimrc in the home directory.

once i set up a .vim in the home directory, when i want to (for example) add a plugin, do i just simply create a /.vim/plugin directory and do the package install there? and how does the linking work?

if anyone could link to an appropriate document describing the proper configuration of a .vim/ in your /home and /usr directory it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It will indeed be easiest to reinstall, and start with a clean `~/.vim/` and `~/.vimrc`. For a structured `~/.vim/`, you need a plugin loader like [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), or plugin manager like [NeoBundle](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim) or [Vim-Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). (I vote for NeoBundle, but it is a matter of taste.) The instructions for each plugin will tell you how to proceed.